# Consultar por dato de otra tabla MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda, quiero saber si es posible consultar un dato de una tabla y compararlo con otro dato de otra tabla, me explico, tengo una tabla mesa la cual tiene su id, y otra tabla pedido la cual tiene como FK el id de la mesa de la tabla anterior, mi consulta es, ¿se puede realizar la siguiente consulta?:

```
SELECT Id FROM mesa WHERE Id = pedido.Id_mesa
```

Si es posible favor me corrigen si está mal la consulta, se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos!.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicar en el FROM todas las tablas que se vas a integrar y luego si puedes hacer el condicional con las distintas tablas.

```
SELECT m.id FROM mesa m, pedido p WHERE m.id = p.id;
```

Comment: OK muchas gracias, probaré con eso :)